# Windows server 2016 Administrator account has no permissions

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016, user-management, sysadmin

I was changing settings around so that users can only use specific applications; however, I didn't realize that it was going to affect admin rights in the same way.

The error I'm receiving is this:

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

The setting I changed was to limit the user accounts ability to to only allow specific applications to run in the group policy settings.

Local Group Policy Editor -> User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System ->Run Only specified Windows applications

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Can you add some information about what settings you were changing?  Any detail you can add would help.

Comment: Edited. I was changing which applications a user could run.

Comment: Start the MMC , select File, Add SNAP IN, Select Group Policy Object Editor and click add , then you will have a BROWSE button available, click on it and then go to the USERS TAB and select Non-Administrators, that will only apply the policy to non admin users.

Comment: I am unable to start mmc because it gives me the same error. even with admin privleges

Comment: Alright I managed to get to mmc however once I follow your instructions it still gives me access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Press Control-Alt-Delete and select Task Manager.
- In the File menu, select Run New Task and enter `gpedit.msc` as the name of the program to run.  Make sure you select the "Create this task with administrative privileges" checkbox.

You should then be able to disable the "Run only specified Windows applications" setting and things should be back to normal.

Comment: I tried this but even task manager is unusable.

Comment: Curious; according to the documentation, it should have worked.  Try booting in Safe Mode With Command Line.  Failing that, if you can boot to removable media, you can try [the sethc trick](https://superuser.com/a/247953/96662) or [this offline registry modification](https://harryjohnston.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/resetting-a-password-in-windows-7-or-windows-vista/) to get a command line window up and run gpedit from there.